# 32bit Ubuntu do-release-upgrade to 18.04

Tags: do-release-upgrade, 18.04

Just a very quick q: will it be possible to upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 LTS on a 32 bit machine using do-release-upgrade?

I appreciate there won't be an official iso image, but can it be done through the Software Updater or via the command line?

I'm asking because gnome-shell (3.26.2) has a memory issue in 17.10 and so needs restarting every so often, and moving to a LTS would solve this problem.

Comment: 18.04 isn't yet released, and until it is, it's not an LTS.  There's also no guarantee that 18.04 won't have the same problem.  In theory you should be able to `do-release-upgrade` to 18.04, but that's not yet an open option unless you want to try and upgrade *now* ahead of the release (though you lose support options via Ask Ubuntu for 18.04 questions until 18.04 is released)

Comment: I was assuming that 18.04 would be LTS for 32-bit

Comment: Just a quick comment on this q: the version of the new Ubuntu (18.04) is reported as "18.04 LTS" so it probably is LTS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding is that the 32-bit distribution will continue to be supported for now, but that 32-bit iso images with installers, etc. will not be produced.

So yes, you will be able to upgrade but not do a fresh 32-bit install.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is YES. There is no more i386 images and installers, but repos for i386 Ubuntu 18.04 is exists and up to date.
Update from 17.10 to 18.04 should be made without any problem (albeit i personally update only 16.04 to 18.04 it was flawless).